# How do I align the contents of app bar layout to horizontal

Tags: android, layout, android-appbarlayout

I have an activity with coordinator layout for which I have app bar layout and include an scrolling content

All the items of the app bar layout are by default arranged vertically and also when I override an menu item for the app bar layout it is not visible so I used an button in the app bar layout

I tried changing the orientation to horizontal by writing in the xml but the scrolling content is coming over the app bar layout

Kindly help me to correct this issue and also how to include a menu item for this layout

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".AddItem">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:background="#252A4E">

        <TextView
                android:text="Item :"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4pt"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25pt" android:id="@+id/tvItem"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#F8F6F6" android:textSize="15pt"
                app:fontFamily="@font/averia_libre" />
        <TextView
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4pt"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25pt" android:id="@+id/tvElevatorNo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#F8F6F6" android:textSize="15pt"
                app:fontFamily="@font/averia_libre"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="72pt"
                android:onClick="AddElevator"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_done_white_18dp"
                android:id="@+id/ibComplete" tools:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_done_white_18dp"
                android:tint="#F9FBE7" android:background="#252A4E"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_add_item" android:layout_height="674dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the xml

Comment: Yeah sure I will upload it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AppBarLayout` extends a `LinearLayout`. So, if you need to create a more complex layout, you must encapsulate your views inside another `ViewGroup` such as `RelativeLayout` or even a `ConstraintLayout` etc.

Something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvElevatorNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25pt"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvItem"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibComplete"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any solution for using menu item

Comment: With menus, usually, you must add a toolbar and the menus will be inflated added to the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#252A4E"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Item :"
                android:textColor="#F8F6F6"
                android:textSize="15pt"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvElevatorNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25pt"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#F8F6F6"
                android:textSize="15pt"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvItem"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvItem"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvItem" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibComplete"
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="#252A4E"
                android:onClick="AddElevator"
                android:tint="#F9FBE7"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvElevatorNo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvElevatorNo"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_add_item"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a layout like this:
Coordinator layout> app Bar layout>then the stuff which is needed to be scrolled with the screen scroll.
Then just add constraint layout inside app bar layout and inside of that constraint layout add your top views and allign them with constraints.
To enable the scroll for this constraint layout stuff, you have to add this attribute:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

in the constraint layout. And it will work definitely.
Thank you, I hope it would work for you.